# Nexus 5X, Gmail draining battery after may update

Tags: battery-life, gmail, nexus-5x

Ever since the may update, the gmail app has been consuming a crazy amount of battery.  My battery used to last like 16 hours, now it's only like 5 hours.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Update of what? Play store or OS- if  OS which one? How did you conclude gmail as culprit? Rooted Device? Are you using amplify? Please edit your question adding details and Screenshots that can help

Comment: Ok, I'll add more when I get a chance

Comment: If you are using Amplify, don't limit *icing* wakelock - that breaks a lot of things with latest  play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue went away after the latest app update (Sometime around June 1st).   Hope this helps!